# Why is my program exceeding the time limit?

Tags: java, string, performance

There was a question called string swap on codechef (https://www.codechef.com/problems/SSWAP)
It said that my program was exceeding the time limit. So, how can I improve my program?
Here is the code-

```
import java.io.*
class StringSwap {
    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader k = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        byte t = Byte.parseByte(k.readLine());
        String s;
        int d, l;
        for (int i = 1; i <= t; ++i) {
            s = k.readLine();
            d = Integer.parseInt(k.readLine());
            l = s.length();
            for (int j = d - 1; j < l; ++j) System.out.print(s.charAt(j));
            for (int j = d - 2; j >= 0; --j) System.out.print(s.charAt(j));
            System.out.println("");
        }
    } // end of main
} // end of class
```

Comment: This might belong on [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than here.

Comment: Don't print in the loop, append to a StringBuilder in the loop and then print both buffers in one shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the time complexity of your solution, which is O(n ^ d), which sucks.

This can be solved in constant time, ie O(1) if you analyze the overall effect of the repeated operation.

Spoiler solution:

> `String tail = str.substring(0, d);`
> `String result = str.substring(d - 1) + ((str.length() % d) % 2 == 0 ? new StringBuilder(tail).reverse() : tail);`
>
> <sub>Disclaimer: Code may not compile or work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>